# Ruby : uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't know what I'm missing here, unable to call a function inside an another function in ruby

Example:

```
def test()
  puts WB_A
end

# Top level components
def WB_A
  {
    'A'            => 'Apple',
  }
end

test()
```

Results in:

> main.rb:2:in `test': uninitialized constant WB_A (NameError)  from main.rb:12:in`'

Please let me know what's the mistake

Comment: I guess you cant declare methods with upper case symbols in name. Change it to `wb_a` or use a constant `WB_A = { 'A' => 'Apple' }`

Comment: @MartinZinovsky, Thanks It works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Ruby user's guide](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/constants.html):

> A constant has a name starting with an uppercase character.
>   It should be assigned a value at most once.

Just change to lowercase it will work:

```
def test()
  puts wb_a
end

# Top level components
def wb_a
  {
    'A'            => 'Apple',
  }
end

test()
#=> {"A"=>"Apple"}
```

Or, if you will, `wB_A` works too, but not recommended, check tadman's comment below.

Comment: Ruby method and variable names should be *lower-case only*. Capital letters are reserved for `CaseName` and `CONSTANT_NAME` cases.